# ¿Por qué falla mi código?

Tags: r, matriz

Estoy en mi primer año de carrera y **nunca había dado programación**. Esta es la Opción 1 (son 4) del proyecto de la carrera, que consiste en crear el juego N en raya (3 en raya, pero en vez de 3, con cualquier número) en el **lenguaje de programación R**. Esta Opción 1 es la parte de la configuración. Aquí el user pone los nombres de los dos jugadores y el número de símbolos seguidos necesarios para ganar (N). En esta parte tengo que crear un archivo de texto y poner una matriz ahí.

Así: `Playersmatrix=matrix("_", 10, 3)` y `colnames(Playersmatrix)=c("Names","Games","Points")`. **IMPORTANTE**: Esto lo hice yo aparte, antes de empezar a programar nada, porque si no, cada vez que inicie la función me va la va a crear de nuevo todo el rato y la idea es que sea siempre la misma matriz, pero modificándose cada vez que dos jugadores ponen sus nombres. Por eso, en la función, Playersmatrix= LA DIRECCIÓN DEL ARCHIVO DE TEXTO CON LA MATRIZ QUE YA CREE.

Ay! Espero que los más avanzados en R puedan entender mi código y deducir qué es lo que quiero hacer. Seguro que es muy sencillo en comparación a todo lo que ya han hecho en su trayectoria como programadores. Muchas gracias y disculpen este texto tan largo. Pego mi código aquí:

```
numberSymbols<-function(symbols)
{
symbols=readline(prompt="How many symbols are required to win? ")
if((symbols==1)|(symbols==2)|(symbols==3)|(symbols==4)|(symbols==5)|(symbols==6)|(symbols==7)|(symbols==8)|(symbols==9)|(symbols==10))
return(symbols)

  else
 {
  print("Number of symbols incorrect")
  numberSymbols(symbols)
 }
 }


Option1<-function()
{


cat("Welcome to NOUGHTS AND CROSSES","\n")


cat("Who are going to play? ")

Player1=readline(prompt="Who is the first player? ")

Player2=readline(prompt="Who is the second player? ")
numberSymbols(symbols)

Playersmatrix=read.table(file="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PROGRAMACIÓN\\Project\\Playerstext.txt")

k=1
repeat
{
{if(Playersmatrix[k,1]=="_") 
{Playersmatrix[k,1]= Player1
k=nrow(Playersmatrix)+1} else {if(Playersmatrix[k,1]==Player1) 
                        {answer=readline(prompt="This player is already in the file. Would you like to change it? ")
                        if(answer=="Yes") {Player1=readline(prompt="Write a new name, please ")
                         Playersmatrix[k,1]= Player1; k=nrow(Playersmatrix)+1} else {Playersmatrix[k,1]= Player1; k=nrow(Playersmatrix)+1}} else {k=k+1}}}

if(k==nrow(Playersmatrix)+1) break
}

a=1
repeat
{
{if(Playersmatrix[a,1]=="_") 
{Playersmatrix[a,1]= Player2; a=nrow(Playersmatrix)+1} else {if(Playersmatrix[a,1]==Player2) 
                        {answer=readline(prompt="This player is already in the file. Would you like to change it? ")
                        if(answer=="Yes") {Player2=readline(prompt="Write a new name, please ")
                         Playersmatrix[a,1]= Player2; a=nrow(Playersmatrix)+1} else {Playersmatrix[a,1]= Player2; a=nrow(Playersmatrix)+1}} else {a=a+1}}}

if(a==nrow(Playersmatrix)+1) break
}
write.table(Playersmatrix, file="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PROGRAMACIÓN\\Project\\Playerstext.txt") 
Playersmatrix=read.table(file="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PROGRAMACIÓN\\Project\\Playerstext.txt") 

Playersmatrix
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida Ana Lib a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Dices que tu código falla ¿te dá un error? ¿cuál y en dónde? ¿o no hace lo que esperas?

Comment: Hola! Vale, haré lo del recorrido en un rato e intentaré ser más concisa! Una vez ejecuto el código, escribo con el teclado el valor para la variable Player1, para la variable Player2 y para symbols, me sale: 

Error in if (Playersmatrix[a, 1] == "_") { : 
  valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
Además: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "Ana") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated  


No sé qué debo corregir porque la estructura de los loops repeat son iguales. Espero que me puedas ayudar. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo ejecuto el código y no da errores, no se si hace lo que pretendes.
Solo le comente las líneas de los archivos y lo ejecuto sin errores. Lo único que hice es comentar las 3 lineas en donde hay una función que escribe o lee archivos. 
El problema que tienes es la conversión de tipos de datos. Tu generas una matriz con celdas del tipo "character". Al guardarla y leerla con read.table obtienes un "data.frame" con el tipo de datos "factor".

```
> class(Playersmatrix)
[1] "matrix"
> write.table(Playersmatrix, "prueba.csv")
> Playersmatrix_leida <- read.table("prueba.csv")
> class(Playersmatrix_leida)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(Playersmatrix[,1])
[1] "character"
> class(Playersmatrix_leida[,1])
[1] "factor"
```

Te aconsejo revisar los tipos de datos y las funciones de conversión. R es muy exigente en cuanto a tipos de datos.